# Ruby on Rails uncaught throw :warden with Devise.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a very strange problem in my Ruby on Rails application. I have controller that looks like this:

```
class PersonReportsController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Live
  load_and_authorize_resource except: [:index]

  def index
    #some code
  end
end
```

and when I try to access it as an unlogged user application throws following error:

```
uncaught throw :warden
```

But when I delete from my controller:

```
include ActionController::Live
```

everything works fine...
Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is explained here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2332

> Wrapping my routes in an authenticate do...end block is a great
>   workaround